# Why null returned even changed in a override method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android app with Firebase Realtime Database. Now, I am looking for `UserProfile` object after executing the query. Therefore I wrote following to get `UserProfile`.

Here is my `UserProfile` class

```
public class UserProfile {

    @NonNull
    private  String id;
    @NonNull
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String image;
    @NonNull
    private String email;
    @NonNull
    private Date created;
    private Date updated;

    // constructor, getter, setter & toString ... 
}
```

And the database structure is like the following.

```
userProfile
|__ hD77qeMX3IPQcKGcuSBOgJOIhHk2
    |__ created
    |   |__ date: 22
    |   |__ day: 0
    |   |__ hours: 21
    |   |__ minutes: 26
    |   |__ month: 3
    |   |__ seconds: 6
    |   |__ time: 1524421566951
    |   |__ timezoneOffset: -180
    |   |__ year: 118
    |__ email: "first_name.last_name.2018@gmail.com"
    |__ firstName: "first_name"
    |__ id: "hD77qeMX3IPQcKGcuSBOgJOIhHk2"
    |__ lastName: "last_name"
```

Here's where I am getting the error.

```
// query method
public UserProfile getUserProfile(String id) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userProfile");
    final UserProfile[] userProfile = {null};
    Query query = databaseReference.child(id);//orderByChild("id").equalTo(0);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                userProfile[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                // print statement for userProfile[0] shows the UserProfile exactly! which is not null
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return userProfile[0];
}
```

`onDataChange` method grab the actual UserProfile from Firebase but finally `getUserProfile` method returns null. What is missing to get `UserProfile` from `getUserProfile` method?

Comment: SHow us both your UserProfile class and your database structure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the point of asynchronous execution here. When you are adding the listener for retrieving the value from your firebase database, the data is not immediately available to be returned to the caller function. The data will be available inside `onDataChanged` method after finishing the execution of the background `AsyncTask` for fetching data from firebase.

Answer (score 2):

Firebases calls are async, and by returning a value from your method you're doing it synchrounously. Your result won't have reached the `userProfile` array yet.

```
public UserProfile getUserProfile(String id) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userProfile");
    final UserProfile[] userProfile = {null};
    Query query = databaseReference.child(id);//orderByChild("id").equalTo(0);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                userProfile[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                // print statement for userProfile[0] shows the UserProfile exactly! which is not null
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return userProfile[0];
}
```

SO, when you method executes it will "schedules" the event listener and finally the line  `return userProfile[0]`; will be executed imediately. Then later when the async call returns a value the onDataChange method will be called and you'll get a result.

You need to call a method and use your data within the onDateChange method, because that's when your data will be ready.

```
public void getUserProfile(String id) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userProfile");
    final UserProfile[] userProfile = {null};
    Query query = databaseReference.child(id);//orderByChild("id").equalTo(0);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                userProfile[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                // update ui here
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

What I usually do is write an UI update method and use it within onDateChanged();

```
public void updateUI(UserProfile profile){
//update UI with profile
}


public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    userProfile[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                    updateUI(userProfile[0]);
                }
            }
```